# Pyenv Installation on Windows 11: 'python' Terminal Command Not Responding; Seeking Resolution

Tags: python, windows, command-line, environment-variables, pyenv

I have recently installed Python on my Windows 11 machine using pyenv. However, I have encountered an unusual issue where the "python" terminal command is non-responsive; it doesn't produce any output or error messages.

I have meticulously verified that all the necessary environment variables are correctly configured, and I have also disabled the system alias for App Execution of Python. Interestingly, if I use "python.bat" instead of "python," I can successfully access a Python shell with the currently set global version via pyenv. However, my objective is to have the "python" command working as intended, not relying on "python.bat."

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this matter?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Show us the output of `where python` in a cmd window.